# Why I get The type test for T cannot be checked at runtime

Tags: scala, scala-3

Piece of code below, of which purpose is to validate Either or Option success fails the build at `case Right(s:T) => s:T` and at `case Some(s:T) => s` and generates the message "**the type test for T cannot be checked at runtime**". But if in **build.sbt** I disable/remove `scalaCoptions "-Xfatal-warnings"` the build won't fail. Scala version 3.1.2 and sbt version is 1.6.2.

```
def validateResults[T, A](payloadValue:A, callerName: String, defaultReturn: T):T =
  payloadValue match
    case Right(s:T) => s  /* the type test for T cannot be checked at runtime */
    case Some(s:T) =>  s  /* the type test for T cannot be checked at runtime */
    case Left(e) =>
      errorHandlingLog[Either[_, _]](callerName, Left(e))
      defaultReturn
    case None => errorHandlingLog[Option[_]](callerName, Option(None))
      defaultReturn
```

Any ideas, why this is fatal with using `scalaCoptions "-Xfatal-warnings"` option and is there more idiomatic approach for addressing those validations?

Comment: What is the point of this code? What if `payLoad` is not an `Either` or an `Option`? if you want to abstract over a generic `getOrElse` then rather define your own typeclass.

Comment: _"and most certainly have to be modified to accommodate other types"_, but your code says that it works for any type. - _"For what comes to getOrElse, it has limitations, because it won't carry the exception information"_, you can use `fold` for that. - I personally would just work in terms of `Either`, an `Option` can be easily converted to `Either` before passing downstream.

Answer (score 1):

> why this is fatal with using scalaCoptions "-Xfatal-warnings" option

This option makes warnings treated as fatal errors. The error you got is usually a warning and thanks to this config it was treated as an error, thus failing the build.

It's a good practice to have this option to catch case like the one you found which would silently not work as intended at runtime otherwise.

> is there more idiomatic approach for addressing those validations

First, you need to understand the issue raised by the warning/error here: generic types in the method are not preserved in Java (thus Scala) at runtime, they are only available at compile time.

In Scala however, there is a feature called `ClassTag` that allow to retain the generic type at runtime as well.

You can use it like this:

```scala
def validateResults[T : ClassTag, A](payloadValue:A, callerName: String, defaultReturn: T):T =

// Or with the implicit syntax:
def validateResults[T, A](payloadValue:A, callerName: String, defaultReturn: T)(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]):T =
```

And that's it, Scala compiler will "inject" the type `T` so that it is available at runtime and can be used for type checking. Nothing to change in the method body.